# #define directive memory storage

Tags: c++, c

When I declare something like

```
#define VAR 1
```

where will the 1 value be stored? I don't think in the heap, nor the stack.. could it be in the .bss section?

Comment: int test = VAR; and int test = 1; are the same. Preprocessor does not store anything.

Comment: It's not stored at all. The preprocessor only does textual substitution, i.e. it replaces every occurence of the text `VAR` with the text `1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not stored anywhere. It is used only during the preprocessing stage of compilation. You can think of it as just a text replacement of `VAR` with `1` throughout your code. After this has been done, the macro itself no longer exists in your program.

Consider the following example:

```
#define VAR 1
int x = VAR;
```

This is simply preprocessed into:

```
int x = 1;
```

It is then *this* code that is compiled as C++. So the macro `VAR` didn't take up any space at all. The object defined by `x` may very well do, however.

Answer (score 3):

The `#define` is purely a pre-processing artefact. Its value will not even reach the compiler if the macro is not used. If it *is* used, then the answer to your question will depend on *how* it's used.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored *wherever you actually use `VAR`*, because all you're defining here is a text-substitution rule for the preprocessor.

```
#define VAR 1
int x = VAR;
```

Before your source is compiled, the preprocessor will reduce this to:

```
int x = 1;
```

In this case, the `1` value is stored in `x`.  The `VAR` symbol is effectively erased prior to compilation.

Answer (score 1):

It is only `#define VAR 1`. so only... defines. It will not cause any memory allocation, it is used only by a **preprocessor** to sabstitute all ocurrences of `VAR` with defined value 1. Just a textual concept.

Answer (score 1):

compiler will replace all # define varables used in program with values while object code is getting generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, you can use it with the option -E. With this option, you can see the output of the source code with the substitution of #defines performed (also the #includes, etc)

```
gcc -E whatever_file.c
```

It's Very useful when you are debugging complex macros